# to accelerate mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, join, query-optimization

I have this query in MySQL. This query is taking too long to run, and I know the problem is the selectors `(coalesce ((SELECT ...)`, I do not know how to speed up a query, via join.

I am hoping some of you SQL gurus will be able to help me.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT CONCAT(d.PRIJEVOZNIK, ' ', d.VOZAC_TRANSFER) 
         FROM dokum_zag as d
         where d.SIFKNJ='NP' and
               d.ID_VEZA=dokum_zag.ID and 
               d.korisnicko_ime=dokum_zag.korisnicko_ime 
         ),'') as PRIJEVOZNIK,
      (RELACIJA_TRANS_VOZ_TRANS) as RELACIJA_TRANS_VOZ, 
      (PRIJEVOZNIK_POVRATNI_TRANS) as PRIJEVOZNIK_POVRATNI, 
      (VAUC_KNJIZENO_TRANS) as VAUC_KNJIZENO, 
      ID_NALOGA, 
      ID_NALOGA_POV, 
      ID_VAUCHER, 
      DOLAZAK, VRIJ_TRANSFER,ODLAZAK,VRIJEME_LETA_POVRAT ,BRDOK, NOSITELJ_REZ, RELACIJA_TRANS, VOZILO_NAZIV, BROJ_NALOGA,BROJ_NAL_POV,BROJ_VAUCHER,BROJ_SOBE,VALIZN,PAX, MPIZN,ID 
FROM
    dokum_zag 
WHERE 
    korisnicko_ime = '10' and 
    ((DOLAZAK='2015-07-30') or (ODLAZAK='2015-07-30')) and 
    STORNO <> 'DA' and 
    SIFKNJ = 'TR' and 
   ((YEAR(DOLAZAK)= '2015') or (YEAR(ODLAZAK)= '2015')) 
order by 
   (CASE WHEN DOLAZAK < '2015-07-30' THEN ODLAZAK ELSE DOLAZAK END) , 
   (CASE WHEN DOLAZAK < '2015-07-30' THEN VRIJEME_LETA_POVRAT ELSE VRIJ_TRANSFER END), ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a DB structure, and a description of what you want to extract it's a bit hard to help you.

From a logical point of view, somethings are redundant, for example

```
((DOLAZAK='2015-07-30') or (ODLAZAK='2015-07-30')) and 
...
((YEAR(DOLAZAK)= '2015') or (YEAR(ODLAZAK)= '2015'))
```

The year part isn't necessary since the year is specified on the first two.

Another thing that might be making the server nuts, is that weird `order by` clause, since it changes from record to record (test this setting it fixed on a field).

You can also check if your indexes are properly set for all the fields on the external `where` clause, and those which are not numeric, are not varchars (for example `SIFKNJ` and `STORNO` should be `char(2)` ).

The `coalesce` part can be solved via an `outer join`, so it doesn't get calculated on each row. But that depends on what and how you want to extract from the database... (since that subquery has it's own fields on the `where` section... weird)

Hope this somehow helps

Comment: SIFKNJ and STORNO is char(2), (YEAR(DOLAZAK)= '2015') or (YEAR(ODLAZAK)= '2015') I moved  go away , Query execution time is 8.2504 sec, If you strip off   (coalesce ((SELECT ...), the query execution time 0.3559 sec,

Comment: table dokum_zag , has 223957 records,

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(korisnicko_ime, SIFKNJ)
```

(in either order) may help

Turning the correlated subquery into a JOIN may help.

```
((DOLAZAK='2015-07-30') or (ODLAZAK='2015-07-30')) and 
((YEAR(DOLAZAK)= '2015') or (YEAR(ODLAZAK)= '2015'))
```

is a bit weird.  This might help:

```
( SELECT ... 
     AND DOLAZAK ='2015-07-30' AND ODLAZAK >= '2015-01-01'
                               AND ODLAZAK  < '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
) UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ... 
     AND ODLAZAK ='2015-07-30' AND DOLAZAK >= '2015-01-01'
                               AND DOLAZAK  < '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
) ORDER BY ...
```

To help that reformulation, add 2 composite indexes:

```
INDEX(korisnicko_ime, SIFKNJ, DOLAZAK, ODLAZAK)
INDEX(korisnicko_ime, SIFKNJ, ODLAZAK, DOLAZAK)
```